# How to update the hard disk device drivers for a ghosted hard drive image so it can run on different hardware: Ultra ATA > SATA

Tags: hard-drive, drivers, ghost-image

I've ghosted a Winxp machine from one laptop with Ultra ATA drive, and would like to set it up on another laptop as a multiboot option on another hard driver with a SATA drive. I can install the partition fine but if i make it active and try to boot it it blue screens. The blue screen is so fast i cant even read it, other than to make out it's saying "something", im picking probably hard drive as it goes through POST fine.

So basically i would like to boot into my Win7 OS, and then somehow manipulate the XP partition to use updated drivers for the new hard drive/laptop so that i can then at least boot into the XP OS on the new machine and update all the other drivers in safe mode or whatever to get it to run.

I assume someone is going to tell me to just do a fresh install, but that kinda defeats the purpose of ghosting at this point. There is a significant amount of personalisation, development setup on the XP machine that i would like to just transfer as is. As it stands ive invested minmal time in getting it to run, just a ghost and recovery and then a blue screen boot or two, so its still well worth it to me, time wise to try this way. Thanks.

Comment: If you can get into Safe Mode (it wasn't clear from your question), you might be able to get around this by starting up in Safe Mode and then allowing the OS to install your drivers, then rebooting.

Comment: Hi there, no unfortunately i cannot get into safe mode. That is whre I am trying to get to for other drivers etc. :) It bluescreesn right after POST.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know [Paragon](http://www.paragon-software.com/) makes some [tools for injecting drivers into a backup image so it can boot on different hardware](http://www.paragon-software.com/home/brs/cat_recovery_scn1.html).

[Rumor has it, it works fine with ghosted drives.](http://www.theforcefield.net/forums/index.php?topic=3723.0;wap2)

(Disclosure: I received a free NFR copy of several Paragon products, including Adaptive Restore.  They've worked great for me so far, but I haven't tried a restore to dissimilar hardware yet.)

Comment: I've actually used Acronis Backup and Recovery but the same technique basically applies.... Get a thrid party tool. Click a couple of buttons and your all done. Key terminology/product part is "Universal Restore" option.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe adjust your computer so that is in AHCI mode?  Or try restoring your image in a virtual machine, which may have a compatible storage controller.

If you haven't destroyed the original machine, you can probably pre-install the driver on the machine before you take your image with Ghost.

Comment: Looks interesting. I'll try the Paragon method above (simply becuase alot of the heavy lifting may have already ben done) and then if that fails try the AHCI method you have suggested. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [NirSoft's BlueScreenView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/trans/blue_screen_view.html) to understand the exact issue to troubleshoot?

Not sure if this would work, but if the old PC is still available, uninstall the drivers, shutdown, and ghost (assuming you're ghosting from a boot CD?). In theory, could XP install the drivers while booting up?

Good luck. Perseverance often pays off.

Comment: Yes. XP machine is still as is. Just a bit slow. Hence the upgrade. I intend to kepp it as is for a trusty back up in case the new machine, dies or gets stolen ;) I will look into the Nirsoft now. thanks. (update) Download links appear stale and broken. :(